# Flutter: How to create a new list with only one class member?

Tags: flutter

I have a class named `Recyclable` with many members, including `title`, `description`, and `recyclable`. I then created an object named `recyclable` using the class `Recyclable` as follows:

```
List<Recyclable> recyclable = [
  Recyclable('myTitle', 'myDescription', 'is recyclable'),
  Recyclable('myTitle2', 'myDescription2', 'is recyclable'),
];
```

Now, I want to copy the object `recyclable` but only with the `title` information. In other words, I want to create a list named newInfo as below:

```
List<String> newInfo = List.from(recyclable.title);
```

However, there is a red underline below `.title`, and I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below :

```
List<Recyclable> recyclable = [
    Recyclable('myTitle', 'myDescription', 'is recyclable'),
    Recyclable('myTitle2', 'myDescription2', 'is recyclable'),
  ];

  List<String> newInfo = recyclable.map((item) {
    return item.title;
  }).toList();
  print(newInfo);
  //[myTitle, myTitle2]
```

The Recyclable class :

```
class Recyclable {
  String title;
  String description;
  String isRecyclable;

  Recyclable(this.title, this.description, this.isRecyclable);
}
```